# In FormFile getFileDate() replacement in Struts2 is needed?

Tags: struts2

`FormFile getFileData()` replacement in ***struts 2*** is needed.

whether FileUpload is replacement for FormFile and also for `getFileData()`??

```
FileUpload myFile = fileImportForm.getTheFile();
byte[] fileData = myFile.getFileData();
```

Comment: Have you read and understood the file upload interceptor docs?

Comment: I'm new to struts framework

Comment: Okay. Did you read the file upload interceptor docs?

Comment: I don't have any idea about Struts but in my project i need to use these Framework

Comment: Okay. Read the file upload interceptor docs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574995/573032